# Ajax запрос из моего Wordpress плагина возвращает ошибку 403 с текстом -1

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, плагин

**Много кода для детального анализа, но весь наверняка не имеет необходимости! Для начала рекомендую пробежаться по вставкам текста, уловить суть и перейти к нужному месту кода**

Вот такая проблема, js скрипт (код скрипта ниже) отдаёт ajax запрос и получает ошибку. Детали запроса:

**General**
**Request URL:** https://sitena.me/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
**Request Method:** POST
**Status Code:** 403
**Remote Address:** 185.68.16.162:443
**Referrer Policy:** no-referrer-when-downgrade

**Response**
-1

**Request Headers**
**:authority:** sitena.me
**:method:** POST
**:path:** /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
**:scheme:** https
**accept:** */*
**accept-encoding:** gzip, deflate, br
**accept-language:** ru,uk;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,und;q=0.2
**content-length:** 188
**content-type:** application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
**cookie:** ....*cookie here*....
**origin:** https://sitena.me
**referer:** https://sitena.me/
**user-agent:** ....*user-agent here*....
**x-requested-with:** XMLHttpRequest

**Form Data**
**DATA[NAME]:** test
**DATA[PHONE_WORK]:** +0 (000) 000-0000
**DATA[EMAIL_WORK]:** test@mail.com
**_wpnonce:** fc21bc8a11
**_wp_http_referer:** /
**action:** myeventname

Раньше запрос обрабатывался корректно, я менял не многое, но что и где повлияло так и не смог понять, бьюсь второй день, не могу решить проблему, с формы не могу заказы записать, не доходят до обработки и всё. Пробовал включить логгирование ошибок но так нигде никаких логов и не нашёл.

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);
define('SAVEQUERIES', true);
```

Выручайте!

Проблемный JS скрипт (точно не знаю когда перестало всё работать, но в таком состоянии js файла кажется всё ещё работало, скорее всего проблема не в js, но точно не знаю ничего):

```
// собственно AJAX запрос из файла mypluginname.js
(function($) {
$(document).on('click', 'form.myformclass input[type="submit"]', function(e) {
    var $form = $(this).closest('form.myformclass');
    var data = $form.serializeArray();

    if ( $(e.target).is('[name="submit-1"]') ) {
        e.preventDefault();

        data.push({name: 'action', value: 'myeventname'});
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: window.wp_data.ajax_url,
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(response) {
                console.error(response);
            }
        });

        return false;
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

HTML:

```
<!-- ... в конце head ... -->
<script type="text/javascript">window.wp_data = {"ajax_url":"https:\/\/sitena.me\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php"};</script>
<!-- итоговый html, сгенерированный плагином в упрощенном виде -->
<form class="myformclass">
<input type="text" placeholder="Имя" name="DATA[NAME]">
<input type="tel" placeholder="Телефон" name="DATA[PHONE_WORK]">
<input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" name="DATA[EMAIL_WORK]">
<input type="submit" name="submit-0" value="Сабмит 0 (не ajax, просто сабмитит форму)">
<input type="submit" name="submit-1" value="Сабмит 1">
<input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="fc21bc8a11">
<input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/">
</form>
<!-- в футере -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://sitena.me/wp-content/plugins/mypluginname/includes/mypluginname.js?ver=4.7.3'></script>
```

PHP:

```
<? // functions.php
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myeventname', 'myeventname_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_myeventname', 'myeventname_callback');

add_action('wp_head', 'mypluginname_js_variables');
function mypluginname_js_variables()
{
    $variables = array (
        'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
    );
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.wp_data = ', json_encode($variables), ';</script>';
}
?>
<?php // shortcodes.php

// ... as class ...
static function init() 
{
    add_shortcode('mypluginname_form', array(__CLASS__, 'mypluginname_form_func'));
// ...
    add_action('init', array(__CLASS__, 'mypluginname_register_script'));
    add_action('wp_footer', array(__CLASS__, 'mypluginname_print_script'));
}

// methods of class
static function mypluginname_form_func($attrs, $content)
{
    do_shortcode($content);

    self::$add_script = true;
    $form_items_count = count(self::$form_items);
    $output = '<form class="myformclass">';

    if ($form_items_count) {
        foreach (self::$form_items as $item) {
            $output .= $item;
        }
    }
$output .= wp_nonce_field('send-lead_'.($form_items_count - 1), '_wpnonce', true, false);
    $output .= '<div id="note"></div></form>';

    return $output;
}

static function mypluginname_register_script()
{
    wp_register_script('mypluginname-js', plugins_url('includes/mypluginname.js', __FILE__));
}

static function mypluginname_print_script()
{
    if (!self::$add_script) return;
    wp_print_scripts('mypluginname-js');
}
```

У меня слишком мало информации от Wordpress-а где и в чём заключается ошибка, но судя по debug_backtrace в wp_die // function wp_die( $message = '', $title = '', $args = array() ) { print_r( debug_backtrace() ); // ... 
Который выводит в 0-м элементе следующее:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [file] => ....root..../wp-includes/pluggable.php
        [line] => 1113
        [function] => wp_die
        [args] => Array
            (
                [0] => -1
                [1] => 403
            )

    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [file] => ....root..../wp-content/plugins/mypluginname/functions.php
        [line] => 50
        [function] => check_ajax_referer
        [args] => Array
            (
                [0] => send-lead_3
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [function] => myactionname_callback
        [args] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
            )

    )
```

Это привет из function check_ajax_referer( $action = -1, $query_arg = false, $die = true ), у меня она вызывается в functions.php моего плагина здесь, но всё при тех же параметрах работало. Что изменилось не могу врубиться. Что поменять - не в домёк.

```
function myactionname_callback() {
    ob_start ();


    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && check_ajax_referer('send-lead_'.count($_POST['DATA'])))
    {
        $postData = $_POST['DATA'];

  //...
```

Comment: При необходимости, могу показать больше кода целиком, хоть весь плагин, там всего 3 php и 1 js файлов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема где-то связан с функцией `check_ajax_referer`, которая хорошо описана тут https://wp-kama.ru/function/check_ajax_referer. Посмотрите в примерах использования, возможно у вас `'send-lead_'.count($_POST['DATA']` не совпадает с nonce, где-то созданным с помощью `wp_create_nonce`.

Comment: Ответ помог! Пока писал подумал что что-то не так с nonce/referer, но именно после ответа вывел nonce и оказалось создаётся nonce как wp_nonce_field('send-lead_'.($form_items_count - 1), '_wpnonce', true, false); согласно debug_backtrace проверка вызывается: check_ajax_referer('send-lead_3') поля 3: имя, телефон, e-mail. в проверке check_ajax_referer('send-lead_'.count($_POST['DATA'])) вывел, оказалось 'send-lead_4', submit-ы с name-value, когда был один submit $form_items_count - 1 = 3, submit-а 2 = 4. поправил и запрос прошёл без ошибок. ох и намучился я из-за этой фигни. спасибо!